# Resize the bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-listview, image-resizing, android-image

Im my project I am capturing the image from Camera app and displaying image in **listview** by using following code .
MySimpleCursorAdapter:

```
public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public void setViewImage(ImageView image_v, String id) {

        String path = id;
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        image_v.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

    }

}
```

List.java

```
String[] from = new String[]{DbManager.babyName, DbManager.baby_image}; 
        int[] to = new int[] {/*R.id.list_id,*/ R.id.drname12,R.id.imageView1};//,R.id.list_date};{                 
        MySimpleCursorAdapter   Adapter = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.rowlayout, c1, from, to);       
        list.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

Every things is working fine till this point But when I try to resize the **bitmap** by using this piece of code

```
 Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 200, 200, true);
```

its giving following error :

```
05-22 07:13:07.562: E/AndroidRuntime(478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 07:13:07.562: E/AndroidRuntime(478): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 07:13:07.562: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:380)
05-22 07:13:07.562: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.example.tottal.baby.care.MySimpleCursorAdapter.setViewImage(MySimpleCursorAdapter.java:22)
05-22 07:13:07.562: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:143)
05-22 07:13:07.562: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:256)
```

Comment: is the bitmap 'b' null?

Comment: Did you tried to log your bitmap 'b' to see if its not null before using it?

Comment: your path variable has null...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is here  check this properly

```
 Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
```

your variable `path` or `b` may be null.

check these variable not equal to null then use them.